# laravel api not showing message from request validation

Tags: laravel, validation, error-handling, laravel-5.6, laravel-5.7

im having problems with error handler in my backend laravel api, don't show error message from validation.

routes/api

```
<?php
Route::group([

    'middleware' => 'api',

], function ($router) {
    Route::post('access/sign-up', 'AuthenticationController@signUp');
});
```

AuthenticationController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\SignUpRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;


    class AuthenticationController extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * Create a new AuthenticationController instance.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['signUp']]);
        }


        /**
         * 
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
         */
        public function signUp(SignUpRequest $request)
        {
            //User::create($request->all());
            return response()->json([
                'data' => 'Usuario creado correctamente.'
            ]);
        }
    }
```

SignUpRequest

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class SignUpRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'firstName' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
        ];
    }


}
```

The thing is that when by postman i send password in blank or not send mail for example it send me to main page insted of sending me a json with all the errors like before. I don't know what to do. 
I tryed with custom message in SignUpRequest, but that's not the problem, think some kind of redirect in error handler.

Comment: While You are using the form requests it won't return json use the validator facade inside the controller and send the response if the validator fails

Comment: Could be that in previos version (5.6) I can use that way and work sending me the json with the different errors? How can I use the validation facade instead?

Comment: Thanks for guide me. I resolve adding 
    
    protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json($validator->errors(), 422));
    }

Comment: I think the right approach is to add an exception handler: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/errors

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just add that code to SignUpRequest

```
 use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
 use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;



protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
{
    throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json($validator->errors(), 422));
}
```

Comment: it's works for me. I'm using laravel 10 with vue 3. Thanks

Answer (score 17):

You need to check just one setting must add Accept Type in header data in Postman

Accept : application/json

that is work in my case...

Answer (score 10):

Using the Form request; If validation fails, a redirect response will be generated to send the user back to their previous location. That's why you are redirecting back to the page instead of the response JSON.

Laravel have one protected method "failedValidation" method. Overwrite this method in your form request class.

```
  protected function failedValidation(\Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator $validator)
{

    throw new \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException(response()->json($validator->errors(), 422));
}
```

Comment: I didn't find this even in Laravel's official document, you saved my day, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Update for laravel 8, the first parameter in ValidationException is the Validator class:

```
protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
{
    throw new ValidationException($validator, response()->json($validator->errors(), 422));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR Add the following header: `Accept: application/json`

As mentioned by a few users over here, by default, when a Form Request fails, the application will attempt to redirect the user back to their previous location. That's why you're receiving a webpage instead of a JSON response.

We can also override the "failedValidation" method. But I would recommend setting the following header on the request `Accept: application/json`.

Laravel will return the appropriate response based on `Accept` header. For `application/json` Laravel will return a JSON response with form errors.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, in your App\Exceptions\Handler, you have to register your custom exception handling in register() method:

```
public function register() {
    
    $this->renderable( function ( ValidationException $ex, $request ) {
        
        $response = [
            'ErrorCode' => 'my_error_code',
            'ErrorMessage' => $ex->validator->errors()
        ];
        
        return response()->json( $response );
    } );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this method to your formRequest class. It works in laravel 9

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;

class PostRequest extends FormRequest
{
    protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'Validation errors',
            'data'    => $validator->errors(),
        ]));
    }
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        switch ($this->method()) {
            case 'GET':
            case 'DELETE':{
                    return [];
                }
            case 'POST':{
                    return [
                        'title' => 'string|unique:posts|required',
                        'body'  => 'required',
                        'image' => 'string|nullable',

                    ];
                }
            case 'PUT':{
                    return [
                        'title' => 'string|unique:posts|required',
                        'body'  => 'required',
                        'image' => 'string|nullable',

                    ];
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In laravel 9/10

In my case i have a small `POST` `API` controller that handles a short logic.

I would like to contain it into the class only and not use any `FormRequest` rules as it has only 1 method to create a resource and only 1 parameter

this is what i did:

```
    // use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
    // use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'mac_address' => ['required',new MacArrayCheck]
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json($validator->errors(), 422));
    }
 
    // ... logic here when all validations passes
```

Read more here [Laravel 10 Doc Manual Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#manually-creating-validators)

Answer (score -1):

Just add that code to `App\Exceptions\Handler`:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof ValidationException) {
    return response()->json([
            'status' => false,
            'error' => [
                'type' => 'form',
                'code' => 400,
                'description' => 'Bad request.',
                'detail' => $exception->validator->errors()
            ]
        ], 422);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```